# When purchasing the 13th technology, can you use its power right after doing so?

Tags: untagged

The 13th technology on the manual reads:

> After resolving one or more powerups gained from performing a Main action, you may pay 1 cocoa to gain an additional power-up (same Action Board)

While the main action part on the manual reads:

> Pay the cost in gold as shown on the selected tile and place one
>   of your Technology markers (wooden discs) on it to mark that
>   you have acquired this Technology. Refer to the Appendix for an
>   explanation of the ongoing benefit of each Technology tile.
>
> After placing the Technology marker, advance once on one
>   temple, depending on which column the selected Technology
>   belongs to: for the left column, for the centre column,
>    for the right column
>
> Afterwards, power up one of your workers on the Alchemy (5)
>   Action Board, unless you used the 3rd option when selecting the
>   tile (you used a single power 4 or 5 worker to place your marker
>   on a second-row Technology).

Therefore, you get the power-up after you have already received the technology, and advanced on a temple. Does this mean that when powering-up your die, can you immediately pay one cocoa to gain an additional power-up?

**TLDR:** Can you use the technology 13 power on the same die power-up you get from purchasing the technology?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No you can not.

From the FAQ file on BGG [here](https://boardgamegeek.com/filepage/170040/official-faq-and-clarifications) the following Q and A is included.

> Q: When do Technology benefits trigger? A: Each Technology triggers at
>   most once during your turn. Most Technologies trigger after performing
>   the Main action on the board (or boards) listed at the bottom of each
>   Technology tile. No Technology will trigger during the turn when it
>   was acquired.

I've tried to find evidence to back this up in the rules printed though and could not.